# Copying/Saving Datas to database from a drop down in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview which has 10 columns, one of which is a dropdown. I want to take the selected value from it and save it in a specific column of a database. I want to know how and where to access this dropdownlist. If there is a code it will be useful.

Comment: Do you have any code to add to the question? What type of database? Where does the Gridview get the data from?

Comment: also which event you wanna try this?

Comment: You need to add the AutoPostBack="True" on the Dropdownlist and SelectIndexChanged event and try to get the details and save it to database.

Comment: Thanks everyone i solved it in rowupdating event its like selecting the value from drop down present in the grid to database that is to be stored in the same column